# How to pass an array object from contentscript.js to popup.html?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The popup.html sends a request to contentscript.js. The contentscript.js creates an array and send the repsonse(an array object) to popup.html.

How to pass an array object from contentscript.js to popup.html?

Is there a need of background.html page to get array object from contentscript.js and then pass it on to popup.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//content script
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var result = [{},{},{}];
    sendResponse(result);
});

//popup
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, "request", function(result) {
        console.log("Received from content script:", result)
    });
});
```

*update*: added selected tab id instead of null

Comment: @Girish What are you trying to pass, array of dom objects?

Comment: array...the contentscript extracts data from dom and puts the result in array

Comment: @Girish You cannot pass dom objects, you can pass only objects without circular references (that can be serialized into json).

Comment: basically...i am trying to extract all <h1> header tags value using contentscript and display these headers in popup

Comment: @Girish The more the better. Content script, popup.